# how to give variable access to a pop() function

Tags: c++

I have `SStack.h` and `SStack.cpp` files.

In the `SStack.h` file, there is an `int used` member variable. I want to use a non-static `pop()` method in non-member functions. The only way I can make `pop()` usable in these non-member functions is to declare it `const`. But when I do that, I cannot use `this->used--;` to decrement the `used` member and "pop off" the top element.

Is there a way to get access to that `used` variable in a `const` method?

SStack.h:

```
//CONTENTS: Declares Class SStack, with data members, contructors and member function prototypes
//If you want, you can make minor changes to this header file

#ifndef _StackClass_
#define  _StackClass_



#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;

class SStack
{

        
        public:
                // Constructor
                SStack( int cap);
                // Copy Constructor
                SStack( const SStack& s );
                ~SStack( ); //destructor
                
        // The member function push: Precondition:  the stack is not full.
                string push ( const std::string s);
                
        // The member function pop: Precondition:  the stack is not empty.
                string pop ();

        // The member function top: Precondition:  the stack is not empty.
                string top () const;
                
                bool IsEmpty () const;

        //printing all the elements in the stack
        void print() const;

        int size() const;

        int getCapacity() const;
        

        private:
                int capacity; // Capacity is the maximum number of items that a stack can hold
                std::string* DynamicStack; 
                int used; // How many items are stored in the stack
};


        // NONMEMBER FUNCTIONS for the stack class
        // Postcondition: The stack returned is the union of s1 and s2.
        SStack operator +(const SStack& s1, const SStack& s2);
        
        //Return true if the two stacks contain exactly the same element values in the same order. 
                bool equals(const SStack& s1, const SStack& s2);


#endif
```

SStack.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "SStack.h"

SStack::SStack(int cap)
{
    DynamicStack = new string[cap];
    this->capacity = cap;
    this->used = -1;
}

SStack::SStack(const SStack& s)
{
    capacity = s.capacity;
    DynamicStack = new string[capacity];
    used = s.used;

    for (int i = 0; i < used; i++) {
        DynamicStack[i] = s.DynamicStack[i];
    }
}

SStack::~SStack()
{

}

string SStack::push(const std::string s)
{
    if (used >= capacity - 1) {
        cout << "Stack overflow" << endl;
    }
    else {
        this->used++;
        DynamicStack[used] = s;
        std::cout << s << " pushed onto the stack" << endl;
        return s;
    }
}

string SStack::pop() 
{
    if (used < 0) {
        cout << "stack underflow" << endl;
    }
    else {
        string s = DynamicStack[used];
        this->used--;
        cout << "popped off the top element: " << s << endl;
        return s;
    }
}

string SStack::top() const
{
    if (used < 0) {
        cout << "stack is empty" << endl;
        return " ";
    }
    else {
        string s = DynamicStack[used];
        std::cout << s << " is on top" << endl;
        return s;
    }
}

bool SStack::IsEmpty() const
{
    if (used < 0) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}

void SStack::print() const
{
    int counter = 1;
    for (int i = used; i >= 0; i--) {
        std::cout << counter << ":";
        std::cout << DynamicStack[i] << endl;
        counter++;
    }
}

int SStack::size() const
{
    std::cout << "the size of the stack is:" << used + 1 << endl;
    return used;
}

int SStack::getCapacity() const
{
    std::cout << "The capacity of the stack is: " << capacity << endl;
    return capacity;
}

SStack operator+(const SStack& s1, const SStack& s2)
{
    return 0;
}

bool equals(const SStack& s1, const SStack& s2)
{
    
    if (s1.size() == s2.size()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < s1.size(); i++) {
            if (s1.top() != s2.top()) {
                std::cout << "the stacks are not equal" << endl;
                return false;
            }
            s1.pop(); //does not work because pop doesnt have the const type
            s2.pop();// same as above
        }
        std::cout << "the stacks are equal" << endl;
        return true;
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "the stacks are not equal" << endl;
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In this function:

```
bool equals(const SStack& s1, const SStack& s2)
{
  // ...  
  s1.pop();  // error
  s2.pop();  // error
}
```

you get an error because `pop` is a non-const function, but `s1`, and `s2` are const objects, which means only const member functions can be called on them.

Since `pop` is inherently a non-const operation, it doesn't really make sense to try and make it a const member.

---

Instead, you can implement `equals` without using `pop`. This can be done by making `equals` a `friend` of `SStack` so that it can inspect the underlying storage without having to call `pop` at all.

A similar approach would be to write a member function (`operator==` is a reasonable choice) that compares 2 `SStacks`, and then you can call that function from `equals`.

---

Or you can accept the arguments to `equal` by copy:

```
bool equals(SStack s1, SStack s2) {
  // ...
  s1.pop();  // ok
  s2.pop();  // ok
}
```

which technically solves the problem, and is correct, but can be very inefficient since you are copying around potentially large objects.

Comment: One possibility would be to declare `equals` a `friend` of `SStack` so that it can perform non-destructive inspection of their underlying arrays.

Comment: There is no reason for a comparison function to be popping values from the stacks at all.  Make it a `friend` so it can simply iterate the `DynamicStack` arrays directly.

Comment: Or write `operator==` as a member function and invoke it in non-member `equals`.

Comment: @cigien "*Or you can accept the arguments to `equal` by copy*" - that is not a good idea, especially for large stacks.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Oh, right, I didn't verbalize some of the reasoning there. If you define `operator== const` as a public member function, then that can also inspect the underlying array without modifying it, and then non-member `equals` doesn't have to be a `friend`, it can just use `operator==`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Good point, added the caveat for the copy solution.

Comment: @NathanPierson I like that solution too, and it's slightly different than the `friend` version, so I added that as well. Thanks a lot for the feedback :)

Answer (score 0):

A `const` method cannot alter members of an object.  `equal()` *should* take `const` references as input, but it *should not* be altering the stacks that are being compared.

You can make `equal()` be a `friend` of `SStack` so it can perform a non-destructive iteration of their internal arrays directly (same with `operator+`), eg:

```cpp
class SStack
{
    ...
public:
    ...
    friend bool equals (const SStack& s1, const SStack& s2);
    friend SStack operator +(const SStack& s1, const SStack& s2);
};

bool equals(const SStack& s1, const SStack& s2);
SStack operator +(const SStack& s1, const SStack& s2);
```

```cpp
SStack operator+(const SStack& s1, const SStack& s2)
{
    SStack res(s1.size() + s2.size());

    for (int i = 0; i < s1.size(); i++) {
        res.push(s1.DynamicStack[i]);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < s2.size(); i++) {
        res.push(s2.DynamicStack[i]);
    }

    return res;
}

bool equal(const SStack& s1, const SStack& s2)
{
    if (s1.size() != s2.size()) {
        std::cout << "the stacks are not equal" << endl;
        return false;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < s1.size(); i++) {
        if (s1.DynamicStack[i] != s2.DynamicStack[i]) {
            std::cout << "the stacks are not equal" << endl;
            return false;
        }
    }

    std::cout << "the stacks are equal" << endl;
    return true;
}
```

Alternatively, you can implement a public `const` member `operator==` which `equal()` can then call (and a member `operator+=` for `operator+` to call) without making them be `friend`s, eg:

```cpp
class SStack
{
    ...
public:
    ...
    bool operator ==(const SStack& rhs) const;
    SStack& operator +=(const SStack& rhs);
};

bool equals(const SStack& s1, const SStack& s2);
SStack operator +(const SStack& s1, const SStack& s2);
```

```cpp
bool SStack::operator==(const SStack& rhs) const
{
    if (size() != rhs.size()) {
        std::cout << "the stacks are not equal" << endl;
        return false;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < used; i++) {
        if (DynamicStack[i] != s.DynamicStack[i]) {
            std::cout << "the stacks are not equal" << endl;
            return false;
        }
    }

    std::cout << "the stacks are equal" << endl;
    return true;
}

SStack& Stack::operator+=(const SStack& rhs)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < rhs.size(); i++) {
        push(rhs.DynamicStack[i]);
    }

    return *this;
}

bool equals(const SStack& s1, const SStack& s2)
{
    return (s1 == s2);
}

SStack operator+(const SStack& s1, const SStack& s2)
{
    SStack res(s1.size() + s2.size);
    res += s1;
    res += s2;
    return res;
}
```